# why a function could return the function itself

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am reading django's source code, and i can not understand what this code is doing.

```
def check_password(self, raw_password):
        """
        Return a boolean of whether the raw_password was correct. Handles
        hashing formats behind the scenes.
        """
        def setter(raw_password):
            self.set_password(raw_password)
            # Password hash upgrades shouldn't be considered password changes.
            self._password = None
            self.save(update_fields=["password"])
        return check_password(raw_password, self.password, setter)
```

why the function return itself, why there is no infinite loop?
this a code snippet from **django/contrib/auth/base_user.py**

Comment: It is not calling that function, it calls the imported function from `django.contrib.auth.hashers`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both different functions even if they share the name. One is within a class the other is not. Also the signature is different.

1 parameter (excluding `self`)

```
def check_password(self, raw_password):
        ...
        return check_password(raw_password, self.password, setter)
```

3 parameters

```
check_password(raw_password, self.password, setter)
```

Comment: The fact that these have not the same number of parameters is not that relevant, since if this was defined at the top level, it would still resolve to that function, and raise a `TypeError`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I do think it is important in this case to show him how to detect that they are different functions, it doesn't matter where they are defined. I don't understand the `TypeError` stuff.

Answer (score 1):

It does *not* call the same function. The `check_password` is defined as an attribute of the `AbstractBaseUser` class. But if you call the function, that will resolve to the imported `check_password` function of the `django.contrib.auth.hashers` module:

> ```
> from django.contrib.auth.hashers import (
>     check_password, is_password_usable, make_password,
> )
>
> # …
>
> class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
>
>     # …
>
>     def check_password(self, raw_password):
>         """
>         Return a boolean of whether the raw_password was correct. Handles
>         hashing formats behind the scenes.
>         """
>         def setter(raw_password):
>             self.set_password(raw_password)
>             # Password hash upgrades shouldn't be considered password changes.
>             self._password = None
>             self.save(update_fields=["password"])
>         return check_password(raw_password, self.password, setter)
> ```